# MVC Razor Layout. How to do it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I need a sample or a article that better describe which method to use with the follow layout structure.

Header
Menu
Body
Footer

On my every page, in the Header section, I will show the User Name, User ID and User Access Count information.

How should I render this? With HTML.Action, HTML.RenderAction , HTML.Partial or HTML.RenderPartial?

If I use HTMl.Action ou RenderAction, I must write the function to do it on every controller?

Thanks,
Silva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project in Visual Studio and choose the Internet Application template. That will give you a basic layout you can learn from.

Comment: First of thanks for you reply.

How about this scenario?

My menu section was populate with a DB connection and the string result was saved on a session variable (because I don't want do make a query for every single page). The approach should be same used with the user information? what if this session expires? Should I put this function to get the information again inside the .cshtml file or use the controller of every page?

Comment: I would suggest you don't do that. What if a user leaves the page open and leaves their computer for a couple of hours... the session will have expired and they will be left without a menu and no idea whats going on. Do a google search for either Scott Guthrie, Phil Haack or Scott Hansleman - their blogs have taught me very much.